# Prevent Bixby to rotate my application to portrat mode

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy, bixby

While development of a game that runs only in landscape mode I've found a way to escape landscape mode using Bixby.

So even if I set that my main activity can run only landscape, I set landscape in my AndroidManifest, when I click Bixby button, then my application switches to portrait mode.

This isn't just my application, tested on VLC, games Unity 3D based, Asphalt 9, some of those don't have a support for that and simply crash.

Is there any way to prevent Bixby from doing it?

Here is a video shows how it messes up with Asphalt 9: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSOV7mvgCsw 
(even crashes it, when clicked while loading)

Cheers,

Comment: No, because the button opens the Bixby app which doesn't force the rotation to landscape.

Comment: Hej #samsung, if you read it: Can you add landscape mode to Bixby to don't mess up with applications?

Comment: I think it's a better idea to properly support configuration changes. You won't be able to ask the user to "please don't fold your foldable phone that costed you $2000 while you're using my app tyvm" ;)

Comment: Hi @EpicPandForce: I value your opinion. Please note that some applications aren't designed to run in the portrait mode - adding support of entire UI, layouts just for a case somebody press 'bixby' and this will be displayed for a couple of seconds I believe it's not a good investment,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior has been resolved. Bixby will now correctly overlay in landscape mode when attempting the use case you described.

Comment: We've tested some last release of Bixby and indeed it fixes totally this error. 
@Samsung:Thank you for listening!